# How to handle write/read access to docker volumes?

Tags: prestashop, docker-compose, chmod, chown

I had a hard time to link 2 containers together and was advised to begin using docker-compose. 
So I build the following docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    volumes:
      - "./.data/db:/var/lib/mysql"
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: my-pass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: prestashop
      MYSQL_USER: my-shop
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: my-pass

  prestashop:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: prestashop/prestashop:latest
    volumes:
      - "./.data/themes:/var/www/html/themes"
      - "./.data/modules:/var/www/html/modules"
      - "./.data/override:/var/www/html/override"
    links:
      - db
    ports:
      - "10083:80"
    restart: always
    environment:
      DB_SERVER: db
      DB_NAME: prestashop
      DB_USER: my-shop
      DB_PASSWD: my-pass
```

This works very well and if I visit the page via a reverse nginx proxy I get the initial install wizard.

But if I add the persistent data volumes:

```
volumes:
  - "./.data/themes:/var/www/html/themes"
  - "./.data/modules:/var/www/html/modules"
  - "./.data/override:/var/www/html/override"
```

The wizard will complain about many read/write access.
Why is that? The internal volumes does have the proper chmod already I guess?
So it is only a sync problem I think.
But I tried to chmod or chown the .data folders, but without any success

Comment: I discovered that docker-compose is mapping the volumes, but because the folders are just created, they are empty. Is there a way to sync default data from var/www/html to my host machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this issue.
After **docker-compose up -d** I did copy the internal folders modules, themes and override to the host machine with **docker cp**

Because Prestashop will check if all files are available.

After copying you can run the prestashop install procedure.